# Selecting in MySQL Database

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

What can I do to display rs.getString2 in the next row only after selecting result from rs.getString 1 ?

```
Statement statement = con.createStatement();
     ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select * from state");
     while ( rs.next() ){
       System.out.println(rs.getString(1) + " " +rs.getString(2));
```

Comment: what do you mean? the next row? or next column?

Comment: Its actually in a combobox. So, it would be in the next row.

Answer (score 0):

```
Statement statement = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select * from state");
while ( rs.next() ){
    StringBuilder br = new StringBuilder();
    br.append(rs.getString(1)); //print the column 1 in the current row
    br.append(" "); //add space
    rs.next(); //move to the next row
    br.append(rs.getString(2)); //print the column 2 in the next row
    rs.previous(); //go back to the current row of this current iteration
    System.out.println(br.toString()); //print
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and may I know how do I compile the append method with the below function.

    jcmbAgents.addItem(rs.getString(1));